# Problem 6.4 of Humphreys Lie algebra book

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, proof-explanation

I found a proof of exercise 6.4 of Humphreys book in http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~zhchang/Research/Notes_01_STLA.pdf, but there are a few details I don't understand:

The first one is: Why is $L$ an invariant submodule? (It is obvious a submodule but why is it invariant?)

And the second one: Why is it necessary to use Weyl's theorem to find a one dimensional complement of L? By construction $M=L+F$ so I would think $F$ is already a complement for $L$.

The definition I have of a completely reducible representation $\rho: L \rightarrow gl(V)$ is that for every $\rho$-invariant subspace $U$ ($\rho(U) \subset U$) of $L$ there exists a $\rho$-invariant complement. That is why I needed $L$ to be invariant in order to use Weyl's theorem.

Comment: What's an invariant submodule?

Comment: I can't find "invariant submodule" for exercise $6.4$, page 21. Where exactly is it? Page number, line number?

Comment: As the answer shows, $F$ is not an invariant submodule, whatever you mean by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your first question, but here's an answer to the second one. No, $F$ is not a complement of $L$, because $L.F\varsubsetneq F$ (unless $\delta\equiv0$). In fact, $x.(a,0)=\bigl(0,\delta(x)\bigr)$, which belongs to $F$ when and only when $\delta(x)=0$.